# ORA-20000: Oracle Text error: DRG-10599: column is not indexed where index exists on select "for update"

Tags: oracle

I was trying to update a CLOB column but failed with the column was not indexed error.

I tried to drop and recreate the index but still ran into the same error:

```
create index idx_response_contxt on test (response) indextype is ctxsys.context;

declare
begin
    for i in (select response from test 
              where contains(response,'{"IdType">BANK}') > 0 for update) loop
    dbms_lob.write(i.response, 12, 5444, '111111111111');
    end loop;
end;
/
```

ERROR at line 1:

ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:

DRG-10599: column is not indexed

ORA-06512: at line 4

It seemed like the "for update" disabled the index.  If I ran without contains function, I didn't get any error but very costly:

```
declare
begin
    for i in (select response from test where response like '%"IdType">BANK%' for update) loop    
        dbms_lob.write(i.response, 12, 5444, '111111111'); 
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Any suggestion?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use proper parameter while creating index as it will decide when index will be synchronized. It can be real time or periodical.

```
create index idx_response_contxt on test (response) 
indextype is ctxsys.context PARAMETERS ('SYNC (ON COMMIT)'); -- real time synchronization
```

Above example is real time rebuild index. You can use different clauses in PARAMETER to rebuild at configurable time. Like `'(SYNC (EVERY "SYSDATE+1/24")'` -- will synch every hour, periodical

Use this as per requirement.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt the index with "PARAMETERS ('SYNC (ON COMMIT)')" and ran the query again, but no use because it still didn't see the index and gave "ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10599: column is not indexed" error.

Any other suggestions?  Thanks.